Folders created in terminal not showing with ls or in the GUI
I'm new to Linux so I'm following a guide. I've been trying to create a folder unraidshare1 in the media directory:
sudo mkdir  -p /media/unraidshare1

No error message but no folder shows up in the media directory in terminal nor in the GUI.
Figuring the -p might me the problem, I go directly into the media directory and try:
sudo mkdir  /unraidshare1

A message shows:
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/unraidshare1’: File exists

There however is no folder or file. ls and ls -a shows an empty media folder. Same in the GUI, I tried to F5 multiple times with no change.
If I make the folder in the GUI it shows up instantly in the GUI with no message about the file already existing. It also shows up in terminal.
I don't know what the command ls / does exactly but when I run that command in terminal after deleting the unraidshare1 folder I created in the GUI it shows an "unraidshare1" folder img that I have no idea where it is or how to access it.
Any help is appreciated

Are you sure you wrote mkdir -p /media/unraidshare1 not mkdir -p /media /unraidshare1? Because it looks like you actually created unraidshare1 at the root of the filesystem (/). That would be consistent with the error message when you tried sudo mkdir /unraidshare1 (the command to make /media/unraidshare1 from inside /media would be sudo mkdir unraidshare1 without the leading / - or sudo mkdir ./unraidshare1 with ./ to indicate the current directory explicitly).

Don't use /media. That directory is used by the automounter, and it will interfere with you. Do sudo mkdir -p /mnt/unraidshare1. /media is reserved, according to the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard. See the Filesystem Hierarcy Standard at https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml, or read man hier.

You have created a directory in the root folder. You need to read this I think: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-path-absolute-relative

@steeldriver I'm absolutely sure I used mkdir -p /media/unraidshare1 since I just copy and pasted it from the guide. Thanks for the info. How do I go about deleting those 2 folders test and unraidshare1 from the root?

@waltinator Ive already mounted the data folder I wanted in the media folder: sudo mount -t nfs 192.168.104.11:/mnt/user/data /media/data is this a problem?

Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].
